# import pandas error in Spyder

Tags: python, pandas

I got this error message in Spyder,

```
import pandas as pd
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       import pandas as pd
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line
>   42, in 
>       from pandas.core.api import *
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line
>   7, in 
>       from pandas.core.algorithms import factorize, unique, value_counts
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py",
>   line 10, in 
>       from pandas.core.dtypes.cast import maybe_promote
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'maybe_promote'

However if I use cmd, it goes well without any problem.
Please suggest a way to fix this problem

Comment: can you take a look at this https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/1758

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your Anaconda Prompt if you've installed pandas within an Anaconda environment. In that case, you need to launch the spyder after activating that particular environment.
Let's say, the pandas is installed within an environment named 'myenv', then type the following two commands in your Anaconda prompt:

```
activate myenv
spyder
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! :) It goes well now!